# angularjs expressjs routing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, url-routing

I have a strange problem while routing a route with two parameters and I can't seem to debug it and find where the error is occurring. Though I have used the following code previously too but for some reason it is not working right now.

I have two angular apps one running on `url '/'` and another on `url '/dashboard'`

Now, on my app A on url '/' there is no such problem but when I am logged in and move to app B with this configuration -

```
angular.module('student').config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
    $routeProvider
        .when('/dashboard', { templateUrl: '/partials/dashboard/student/index',
            controller: 'StudentDashBoardController'
        })
        .when('/profile', { templateUrl: '/partials/dashboard/student/profile',
            controller: 'ProfileController'
        })
        .when('/myfeeds', { templateUrl: '/partials/dashboard/student/myfeeds',
            controller: 'MyFeedsController'
        })
        .when('/student/test', { templateUrl: '/partials/dashboard/student/user',
            controller: 'UserController'
        });
});
```

and the routing configuration in express is -

```
app.get('/dashboard',function(req,res){
        if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
            res.redirect('/403');
        } else if(req.user.roles.indexOf("student") != -1){
            res.render('student');
        } else if(req.user.roles.indexOf("teacher") != -1){
            res.render('teacher');
        } else if(req.user.roles.indexOf("publisher") != -1){
            res.render('publisher');
        }
    });
app.get('/profile',auth.requiresApiLogin,users.renderStudentUser);
    app.get('/student/test',auth.requiresApiLogin,users.renderStudentUser);
    app.get('/myfeeds',auth.requiresApiLogin,users.renderStudentUser);
app.get('/partials/*',function(req,res){
        res.render('../../public/app/' + req.params['0']);
    });
app.get('*',function(req,res){
        res.render('index',{
            bootstrappedUser: req.user
        });
    });
```

now, the function `users.renderStudentUser` is like -

```
exports.renderStudentUser = function(req,res){
    User.findOne({username:req.user.username}).exec(function(err,user){
        if(err){
            res.status(400);
            return res.send({reason:err.toString()});
        }
        res.render('student',{
            user:user
        });
    });
};
```

so, basically it routes the user to the app B. 
I am using it because if a user hits `'/profile'` in the browser directly then the `app.get('*')` route redirects it to the app A at '/' so i have explicitly set three routes for `'/profile','/myfeeds','/student/test'` to redirect them to app B where the angularjs router will take care of each of those routes.
Now, the problem occurs when i try to hit 
`'/student/test'` directly in the browser and I get 404 error message for all the scripts, even the partial file but the view that is rendered is `student` only, as the scripts that are defined in that view are shown with 404 status in console.
surprisingly when i try to hit '/dashboard' it works and then if i go to '/student/test' by a hyperlink like

```
<a href="/student/test"> xyz </a>
```

it works the correct partial file is loaded.

Now, to debug i changed the expressjs and the angularjs routes from `'/student/test'` to '/student' it works both ways that is by hitting this url directly in browser or using hyperlink.

I also tried to rename '/student/test' to `'/xyz/test'` to verify that there are no multiple matches in my expressjs routes for this route.

can anyone suggest now where i made a mistake or, what more information should i provide to diagnose this error, or how should i debug it to find the error.

Comment: I would like to clarify a few things. You mentioned App A and App B how they are different from each other? I am making a wild guess, you might have kept two 'ng-app' attribute in your Application and named them as 'AppA', 'AppB'?

Comment: yes. two modules defined with different dependancies in different files and in the appA file the file containing definition of appB is not present and in the appB the javascript file containing definition of appA is not present and also the jade template of appA has only one ng-app specifying appA and same goes for appB. Also appB is hosted and served by server on a sub-context on url '/dashboard' and appA is served on '/'

Comment: So that's the mistake you are doing. Try to understand that AngularJS is used for building SPA(Single Page Application). We can not have multiple ng-app attributes defined. Let me know if you need help on this.

Comment: But, we can have multiple ng-apps on different pages on the same website. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase here it is specified about that. Now, I am not putting both ng-app attributes in one jade template but putting them in different views.

Comment: Then you are contradicting the sole purpose for which AngularJS is built. It is to replace the part of views in the same single page, and change routes accordingly. If you work with multiple page then how can we call it as Single Page Application. :)

Comment: I know, but they are separated solely for authorization purposes in my application. anyway i solved it by adding base href="/dashboar"